# Calling query: Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie who trying to make my own web app. I got a problem. I've tried to call query from a table with this code to find rank

```
$rank="SELECT student_code, led2dt4engavgfinal, FIND_IN_SET(
    led2dt4engavgfinal,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT led2dt4engavgfinal ORDER BY led2dt4engavgfinal DESC)
    FROM led2deng)
) as rank
FROM led2deng;"; 
$myQry2 = mysql_query($rank, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error());
$myData2 = mysql_fetch_array($myQry2);
```

and I use 
this code to call the data

```
<?php echo $myData2; ?>
```

but it came out

> Notice: Array to string conversion in....

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the result array like this:

```
foreach($myData2 as $row){

  //Now access columns like this
  echo $row["student_code"];
  echo $row["led2dt4engavgfinal"];

}
```

**Update: Try this**

```
<?php 
$rank="SELECT student_code, led2dt4engavgfinal, FIND_IN_SET( led2dt4engavgfinal , (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT led2dt4engavgfinal ORDER BY led2dt4engavgfinal DESC ) FROM led2deng) ) as rank FROM led2deng;"; 
$myQry2 = mysql_query($rank, $koneksidb) or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error()); 
$myData2 = mysql_fetch_array($myQry2); 

foreach($myData2 as $row) {
    echo $row['student_code'];
    echo $row['led2dt4engavgfinal'];
    echo $row['rank'];
}
```

?>

Comment: i am trying to show rank from a column.
+--------------+--------------------+------+
| student_code | led2dt4engavgfinal | rank |
+--------------+--------------------+------+
| S02001       | 16.6                |    2 |
| S02002       | 90                 |    1 |
| S02003       | 0                    |    4 |
| S02009       | 100                |    3 |
| S02021       | 100                |    3 |
+--------------+--------------------+------+
21 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: `echo $row["rank"]` does not work?

Comment: try `var_dum($row)` within foreach to see how the result array is formatted.

Comment: Can you share new code and what is the output?

Comment: <?php $rank="SELECT student_code, led2dt4engavgfinal, FIND_IN_SET(
                  led2dt4engavgfinal
               ,  (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(
                            DISTINCT led2dt4engavgfinal
                            ORDER BY led2dt4engavgfinal  DESC
                         )
                   FROM    led2deng)
                ) as rank
           FROM   led2deng;"; 
    $myQry2 = mysql_query($rank, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error());
    $myData2 = mysql_fetch_array($myQry2);
    foreach($myData2 as $row);
    ?>

Comment: <?php echo  $row["$rank"]; ?>

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'SELECT student_code, led2dt4engavgfinal, FIND_IN_SET( led2dt4engavgfinal , (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT led2dt4engavgfinal ORDER BY led2dt4engavgfinal DESC ) FROM led2deng) ) as rank FROM led2deng

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109610/discussion-between-meathanjay-and-gtviga).